# how to query an array of values using the $ne query in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to query an array of values using the `$ne` query in mongodb?

this is the list i would like to query

```
const movies = [
  {
    name: 'crystal',
    showWatched: 'cars',
    number: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'barbra',
    showWatched: 'moonlight',
    number: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'marry',
    showWatched: 'sunshine',
    number: 3,
  },
 {
    name: 'joy',
    showWatched: 'cooking',
    number: 4,
  },
]
```

this below is the query i tried, i would like to get back everything not equal `"crystal","marry"`  but instead this query below is returning everything

```
const findin = ["crystal","marry"]

db.getCollection('movies').find({name: {$ne: findin} })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but in this case you should use the `$nin` (not in array) operator rather than `$ne` (not equal). Like so:

```
db.getCollection('movies').find({name: {$nin: findin} })
```

You can check it out [here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BWSLaxUCXlv)